# Полезные, спорные, отозванные, но отклонены?

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, история-тревог

На [странице своих тревог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему только "отклонены" в форме краткого прилагательного? Может поменяем на "отклонённые"?

Comment: Ещё не завершено - вижу старый текст.

Comment: @Qwertiy уже вроде обсуждали это, метку меняем, когда перевод добавляем в трансификс. Не?

Comment: Возможно я где-то обсуждение пропустил, но я метку ставлю когда в интерфейсе увижу. И капча мне пока ещё не попадалась... Впрочем, там уже кто-то обработал.

Comment: @Qwertiy под каким-то вопросом по локализации было обсуждение )

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8808/178988 - обсуждаем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поправил [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/string/3501) на "отклонённые".

В transifex, кстати, обнаружилась древняя заметка одного из модераторов:

> [image: заметка]

Ждём подхвата и пересборки.