# Когда ставить [статус-завершено] на вопросы по локализации?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, метки, мета, инструменты-модератора

В вопросах, где требуется изменить или добавить перевод есть несколько стадий, после которых новый перевод появляется на сайте. После какой из них на вопрос следует ставить метку [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)? Очевидно, что когда вариант предложен, ещё рано. А вот когда он утверждён - уже пора или надо подождать, пока он появится в интерфейсе?

Comment: Я и такой, и такой вариант видел у нас в обсуждениях. Лучше, вероятно, когда оно появится в интерфейсе.

Answer (score 6):

На мой взгляд, ставить метку надо только после того, как строка появится в интерфейсе, поскольку:

- Большинству пользователей не важно, утверждён перевод или нет, они видят только интерфейс, поэтому время, когда стоит [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be), а на сайте используется старый вариант, будет сбивать с толку.
- В случае новых фраз уже иногда оказывалось, что в интерфейсе используются не те фразы, которые были переведены и перевод не применялся.

Answer (score 4):

В идеальном мире метка об исправлении проблемы или реализации какого-то предложения должна появляться только тогда, когда есть возможность проверить эту готовность, а пока готовность ещё не видна, ставить метку типа [статус-в-процессе](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5).

Но в реальном мире такая бюрократия не всегда возможна. А из-за, порой, довольно существенного лага между действием, иницирующим разрешение проблемы, и наблюдением готового решения метку можно поставить сразу же, если есть такая возможность, дабы не забыть поставить её вообще. Это относится к любым задачам, не обязательно связанным с локализацией сайта. Просто так получается, что на руСО очень мало участников, имеющих модераторские полномочия (поставить красную метку) и при этом занимающихся решением проблем переводов.

Чтобы минимизировать кол-во ситуаций, когда [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) есть, а реального решения нет (например, как-то криво поправили) надо вручную следить (переодически проверять) за готовностью той или иной проблемы и либо через тревогу «требует внимания модератора» просить поставить метку (если это обычный участник), либо поставить её самостоятельно (модератор). Но, учитывая, что ошибочные решения достаточно редки, можно ставить метку сразу же, как появилась уверенность, что для наблюдения решения проблемы нужно лишь выждать время, требуемое для подкачки строк, пересборки движка и т.п. Пока не будет способа получать автоматические уведомления по тем или иным вопросам, требующих ручной проверки готовности решения, приходится балансировать между вариантами:

- **поставить метку сразу** в надежде, что всё пройдёт как надо, и никто не начнёт возмущаться, почему метка уже есть, а функционала ещё не видать;
- **поставить метку после проверки решения**, но для этого надо либо самому проверять периодически, либо чтобы кто-то другой проверил и поставил соответствующую тревогу.

То есть я бы не стал утверждать какой-то один из подходов, как единственно возможный. К тому же описание метки [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) как раз говорит, что может быть придётся немного подождать, прежде чем трубить тревогу.

Comment: Вообще, я как раз говорил о тревогах для модераторов с просьбой поставить метку. По мне так странно использовать эту тревогу, если проверить ещё нельзя.

Comment: @Qwertiy в вопросе про тревоги ничего не сказано :)